# Sender is set to "deadLetters" when sending a message to Akka Router from outside (Play 2.4)

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, guice

I have some class that sends a message to actor

```
class SenderImpl @Inject() (@Named("routerActor") routerActor: ActorRef) {
   routerActor ! "Hello"
}
```

and an actor class that receives this message

```
@Singleton
class RouterActor @Inject() extends Actor {
   override def receive: Receive = {
       case msg => println(s"sender = ${sender()}")
   }
}
```

RouterActor injected as a router in a separate class:

```
 bindActor[RouterActor]("routerActor", RoundRobinPool(10).props)
```

**Result: sender = Actor[akka://application/deadLetters]**

If RouterActor injected as a single actor:

```
bindActor[RouterActor]("routerActor")
```

**Result: sender = Actor[akka://application/temp/$a]**

Why the sender info is missing in case of router and how could I recover the sender?